# Enabling the Django Admin for a custom User Model with a custom Authentication Backend

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom user model with my own authentication in place. But despite this I am unable to login to Django admin. The page appears but it does not accept my credentials (which are correct). I have included `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` along with my custom authentication backend in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. The `is_staff` and `is_admin` are both set when I check in the shell.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                            'final.backends.CustomBackend',)


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'final.MyUser'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
'final',
'rest_framework',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'final.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication',
)
}
```

Ignore the poor indentations please. They got lost in a copy-paste massacre.

Comment: Could you show your `settings.py`?

Comment: @alecxe Relevant parts of `settings.py` shown.

Comment: Try using single backend. May be you could inherit `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` and override `authenticate` method.

Comment: @sagarchalise I'm not sure how that would make a difference.

Comment: The attribute flag is `is_superuser` not `is_admin` for user to be able to access admin. If your custom authentication is not that different from default implementation, I guess inheriting would be good choice.